# Writing a word with straight lines

Tags: fonts, generative-art

Here is an interesting way to write a word: *(it is from a poster for the International Museum Day 2006; I believe it even won an award at an international design competition)*

[image]

[image]

[image]

by [Boris Ljubicic](http://www.graphis.com/bio/2/boris-ljubicic-1/).

I found this about the poster:

> opis
>
> Plakat je oblikovan kao kompjutorski crtež složen od potpuno ravnih crta u tri osnovne boje. Linije gustoćom razmještaja na
>   površini oblikuju riječ MUSEUM.
>
> Pri ilustriranju teme autor Boris Ljubičić objašnjava da je želio
>   naglasiti specifična obilježja muzeja i mladih. Kako mladi najbolje
>   poznaju nove tehnologije i suvereno se koriste njima, kao sredstvo za
>   izradu crteža plakata odabran je kompjutor. Drugi kriterij koji je bio
>   važan, objašnjava autor, jest vrijeme rada / aktivnosti. Muzeji se
>   upravo s mladima - tom posebnom skupinom posjetitelja, dotiču /
>   razilaze glede pitanja vremena "rada". Za posjetitelje su otvoreni
>   tijekom dana (samo se posebna događanja organiziraju do kasno u noć).
>   Suprotno tome, u kulturi življenja mladih bitan je "noćni život",
>   stoga odlazak u muzej jedan dio te populacije zamišlja upravo u to
>   vrijeme. Stoga autor, poštujući različitosti između muzeja i mladih,
>   konceptualno oblikuje plakat u dvije boje podloge: crnoj (Inv. br.
>   7777), koja simbolizira noć / noćni život, i bijeloj (Inv. br. 7778),
>   koja obilježava dan / dnevni rad.
>
> Dio koncepta bila je i zamisao da muzeji dobiju plakate slučajnim
>   odabirom, neovisno o boji podloge.

Translation by Google Translate:

> description
>
> The poster was designed as a computer drawing of a complex of
>   completely straight lines in three basic colors. Line density
>   distribution on the surface forming the word MUSEUM.
>
> In illustrating the theme author Boris Ljubicic explains that he
>   wanted to emphasize the specific characteristics of the museum and
>   youth. How do young people know best new technology and confidently
>   used them as a means of making art posters selected computer. Another
>   criterion that was important, explains the author, is working time /
>   activities. Museums just with young people - that special group of
>   visitors, touch / disagree on the issue of time "work". For visitors
>   are open throughout the day (only for special events organized until
>   late at night). In contrast, the culture of life of young people is an
>   important "night life", thus leaving the museum a part of this
>   population is that of the time. Therefore, the author, respecting
>   differences between museums and young people, conceptual design a
>   poster in two colors lining: black (Inv. No. 7777), which symbolizes
>   night / nightlife, and white (Inv. No. 7778), which marks the day /
>   daily work .
>
> Part of the concept was the idea that museums receive posters at
>   random, regardless of the color of the substrate.

---

Can it be done by Mathematica, for any word, for any font?

---

EDIT: Just want to add this arrangement of letters and symbols that can be useful for testing of a Mathematica solutions: *(the letters and symbols are grouped by visual properties, so that the quality of a solution can be assessed with less effort)*

### I E L H F T

### M Y Z K N

### A V W X

### D P B R

### O C U S

### Q J G

### 0 3 6 8 9

### 1 2 4 5 7

### + - = _ *

### . , " ' : ;

### & @ # $ %

### < > ^ ~

### ( ) [ ] { }

Comment: Notice that each alphabet is formed (visible) when the density of lines which cross each other exceeds a certain value, and  each different alphabet has a unique  spatial distribution of crossing. Wonder if this can be coded. Just a guess.

Comment: Once again you ask good questions with no effort to find a solution yourself. Damn, you are a good at that.

Comment: This would make an interesting code golf challenge...

Comment: I noticed that a lot of the line segments seem have one end on the outline of the letter. I suspect this makes reaching the target density a lot easier than having lines that cover the whole page or that both ends are a random distance away.

Comment: @Random832 It does. Also, a lot of lines are almost vertical, or around 45 degree. I have strong impression that the original image is done entirely manually.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is another way of making this kind of graphics using version 6 commands. I am not sure how valuable is this different way of making them compared to the other answers of Martin Buettner and kirma, but I do think some of the results look interesting. I was mainly motivated to explore the 3D versions of writing words with straight lines.

### Code (original)

Here is the code. `Text`, `Graphics`, and `Rasterize` are used to get the coordinates of the letters (instead of the Region functions.)

```
Clear[LetterAt];
Options[LetterAt] = {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 120};
LetterAt[letter_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{grm, grmr, mcoords, fontFamily, fontWeight, fontSize},
   fontFamily = OptionValue[FontFamily];
   fontWeight = OptionValue[FontWeight];
   fontSize = OptionValue[FontSize];
   grm = Graphics[
     Text[Style[letter, FontFamily -> fontFamily, 
       FontWeight -> fontWeight, FontSize -> fontSize], {0, 0}], 
     ImageSize -> {100, 100}];
   grmr = Rasterize[grm];
   mcoords = Reverse /@ Position[grmr[[1, 1]], {0, 0, 0}] // N
   ];

LetterCoordsToLines[coords_, offsetSize_Integer, nsample_Integer] := 
   Function[{pair}, 
   Line[({pair[[1]] - offsetSize*#1, 
        pair[[2]] + offsetSize*#1} & )[(pair[[2]] - pair[[1]])/
             Norm[pair[[2]] - pair[[1]]]]]] /@ 
  Table[RandomSample[coords, 2], {nsample}]

LetterCoordsToLines2[coords_, offsetSizeDummy_Integer, nsample_Integer] :=
 Map[Function[{pair}, 
   Line[{2 pair[[2]] - pair[[1]], 2 pair[[1]] - pair[[2]]}]], 
  Table[RandomSample[coords, 2], {nsample}]]
```

### Code (update for version 12.3)

```
Clear[LetterAt];
Options[LetterAt] = {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 120};
LetterAt[letter_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=  
  Block[{grm, grmr, mcoords, fontFamily, fontWeight, fontSize},
   fontFamily = OptionValue[FontFamily];
   fontWeight = OptionValue[FontWeight];
   fontSize = OptionValue[FontSize];
   grm = 
    Graphics[
     Text[
      Style[letter, FontFamily -> fontFamily, 
       FontWeight -> fontWeight, FontSize -> fontSize], {0, 0}], 
     ImageSize -> {100, 100}];
   grmr = Rasterize[grm];
   grmr = ImageReflect[grmr, Top -> Bottom];
   mcoords = Reverse /@ Position[ImageData[grmr], N@{0, 0, 0}]
 ];
```

### Getting coordinates for the letters

We get the coordinates for each letter separately and then translate it accordingly:

```
word = "MUSEUM";
letterCoords =
  MapThread[(
     t = LetterAt[#1, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
       FontWeight -> "Normal", FontSize -> 100];
     Map[Function[{p}, p + {#2, 0}], t]
     ) &, {Characters[word], 
    Range[0, (StringLength[word] - 1)*100, 100]}];
```

Here is how the points for each letter look like:

```
ListPlot /@ letterCoords[[1 ;; 4]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[Point /@ letterCoords]
```

[image]

### 2D writings

We can write the letters by randomly selecting pairs of points for each letter. This command uses unit vectors derived for each pair:

```
palette = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], 
  Riffle[LetterCoordsToLines[#, 100, 700], RandomChoice@palette] & /@ 
   letterCoords}]
```

[image]

This command uses just the difference for each pair or points (as in Martin Buettner's answer):

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], 
  Riffle[LetterCoordsToLines2[#, 100, 700], RandomChoice@palette] & /@
    letterCoords}]
```

[image]

And this command combines the two line drawing approaches together with random coloring:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], 
  Riffle[LetterCoordsToLines[#, 100, 200], 
     Table[RandomChoice@palette, {Length[#] - 1}]] & /@ letterCoords, 
  Riffle[LetterCoordsToLines2[#, 100, 400], 
     Table[RandomChoice@palette, {Length[#] - 1}]] & /@ letterCoords},
  PlotRange -> {{-50, 650}, {-50, 150}}]
```

[image]

### 3D writings

Let as make two flat point writings of each letter:

```
letterCoords3D = 
  Join[Map[Riffle[#, 0] &, #], Map[Riffle[#, 10] &, #]] & /@ 
   letterCoords;
```

and sample the points in the obtained pairs of letter panels:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], 
  LetterCoordsToLines2[#, 100, 600] & /@ letterCoords3D}, 
 ImageSize -> 1000, PlotRange -> {{-50, 650}, All, {-50, 150}}]
```

[image]

Here is another take with the two types of lines combined (the plot is thicker than the previous one because scaled normalized vectors are used):

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], 
  LetterCoordsToLines[#, 100, 100] & /@ letterCoords3D, 
  LetterCoordsToLines2[#, 100, 500] & /@ letterCoords3D}, 
 ImageSize -> 1000, PlotRange -> {{-50, 650}, All, {-50, 150}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

### Update : words in Cyrillic and Katakana

The line effect produces interesting results with more angular symbols.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For me, the first image with "afro" style and orange-yellow-purple-teal-green-blue color pattern is the most beautiful so far. (although its style is different than the style of the original)

Comment: @VividD Thanks! "Afro style" is a good characterization!

Answer (score 67):

Here is a start. I'm sure others will come up with better solutions, but I think from here it's mostly down to finding a better algorithm to pick the random lines.

First, we get ourselves a `Region` representation of the text we want to stylise (thanks to yode for simplifying this part):

```
textRegion = DiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["MUSEUM", FontFamily -> "Arial"]], 
  _Text, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1
]
```

[image]

This is pretty much all you need. Now it's just a question of how to use that region to pick lines. I tried playing with `RegionIntersection` and random lines but that didn't seem to work, so here is another idea: we start by splitting the text into its individual letters:

```
letters = ConnectedMeshComponents@textRegion
```

Then we simply pick a number of random pairs of points within each letter, and connect them with a line, which we extend a bit on both ends:

```
Graphics[
  {
    Opacity@0.2, 
    Line /@ ({2 #2 - #, 2 # - #2} &) @@@ RandomPoint[#, {400, 2}] & /@ letters
  }, 
  ImageSize -> 800
]
```

Voilà:

[image]

Doesn't look quite as neat and organised as your example, I admit. That's where choosing a better way to generate the lines comes in, maybe prioritising those with angle close to ±90 degrees or something.

We can also add colour quite easily, either using completely random colours, or a palette of our choice:

```
palette = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
Graphics[
  {
    Opacity@0.2, 
    {RandomChoice@palette, Line@#} &
      /@ ({2 #2 - #, 2 # - #2} &) @@@ RandomPoint[#, {400, 2}] & /@ letters
  }, 
  ImageSize -> 800
]
```

[image]

Following an idea from Akiiino we can make the letters more pronounced by only selecting points from the boundaries of the letters and not extending all of them:

```
letters = ConnectedMeshComponents@RegionBoundary@textRegion
Graphics[
  {
    Opacity@0.2, 
    Line /@ 
      (RandomChoice[{{2 #2 - #, 2 # - #2}, {#, #2}}] &) @@@ 
        RandomPoint[#, {400, 2}] & /@ letters
  }, 
  ImageSize -> 800
]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the letters become a bit *too* pronounced. This idea could probably be developed further to yield somewhat smoother results though.

They further suggested to pick one point on the boundary and one point in the interior. If we then extend the line only away from the boundary, we should get a more pronounced boundary without actually making the interior less dense than the boundary. Here is the code:

```
letters = ConnectedMeshComponents@textRegion
letterBoundaries = RegionBoundary /@ letters

Graphics[
 {
  Opacity[0.2],
  MapThread[
   Table[
     With[{bdr = RandomPoint[#], int = RandomPoint[#2]},
      Line[{bdr, 2 int - bdr}]
      ],
     400
     ] &,
   {letters, letterBoundaries}
   ]
  },
 ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

[image]

It sort of works, but I'm not sure I prefer it over the fuzzy and simple technique, and it doesn't quite reach the quality of the OP's examples yet.

Comment: Upvote.Or we can simplify your `textRegion` to `DiscretizeGraphics[Text["MUSEUM"],_Text,MaxCellMeasure->0.1]`?

Comment: "maybe prioritising those with angle close to ±90 degrees" - the route that requires least programming effort would be something like rejection sampling; that is, the segment picking can be biased towards vertical lines, and only allow less steep lines, say, 10 % of the time.

Comment: @yode Interesting, I tried applying `DiscretizeGraphics` directly to `Text` earlier but it didn't work without `_Text` pattern. That simplifies things, thank you.

Comment: @J.M. Another idea might be to choose a fixed slope and put lines of that slope through individual random points. There will then be more lines along parts of the letter which are parallel to the slope than those which are perpendicular. Do that for a few different slopes (or vary them slightly about some mean slope) and you might get nice results as well.

Comment: The letters in the original picture are more pronounced due to the fact that their borders are much more visible: a lot of lines start/end exactly at the borders. Maybe choose only points on borders and extend only some percentage of lines (like 50%)?

Comment: @Akiiino Oh, that's a good idea, let me give that a go.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Hmm... The problem seems to be with the lines parallel to edges; maybe, choose one point on border and another randomly inside the letter? I would try that myself if only I could understand the arcane magic you used; sadly, I'm nowhere near that level of understanding yet.

Comment: You might also consider choosing lines according to the kernel density of the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).  I.e., compute this transform to get the density estimate of lines in the entire word and for each letter.  Use the transform of each letter to stencil the word's transform (so that only lines in this letter are used in this letter, but their slopes tend to be similar across all the letters) and select lines from that transform.  Then, with high probability, place 1 or 2 endpoints on the boundary of the letter.  I'd spend time on this, but ... grading.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Perhaps this would make a good challenge on PPCG.

Comment: @mbomb007 Possibly, but getting the spec tight enough seems tricky. I think I'll be staying away from popularity contests for the foreseeable future, and I'm not sure this would work particularly well with an objective image similarity scoring (also we already have a "draw this image with nothing but lines" challenge).

Answer (score 45):

Weighted sampling of line segments based on overlap/non-overlap ratio:

```
Module[{reg}, 
 reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["MUSEUM", FontFamily -> "Arial"]], _Text, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]; 
 Graphics@Line@
     RandomSample[(With[{iarea = 
             Quiet@Area@
                BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
                 RegionIntersection[reg, 
                  Polygon[{#1 + 
                    Normalize@RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/2][#1 - #2]/
                    10, #1 + 
                    Normalize@RotationTransform[\[Pi]/2][#1 - #2]/
                    10, #2 + 
                    Normalize@RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/2][#2 - #1]/
                    10, #2 + 
                    Normalize@RotationTransform[\[Pi]/2][#2 - #1]/
                    10}]] /. _Area -> 0},
           iarea/((2/10) EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] - iarea + 
              1/1000)] & @@@ #) -> #, 
      1000] &@(With[{d = 
        RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3/2], 2]}, {# - d, # + 
        d}] & /@ 
    RandomPoint[Rectangle @@ Transpose[RegionBounds@reg], 10000])]
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh, turning the line into a narrow polygon makes the `RegionIntersection` work? That's clever. :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes... I think line-mesh intersection should really work even otherwise and one should be just be able to check out `RegionMeasure` after that, but it appears that's a bit optimistic. I didn't actually notice you mentioned this problem on your answer, but played with it on my own...

Comment: @kirma Can you perhaps come up with some visually intereresting examples of other words, and other fonts?

Comment: @Vivid, you can do experiments yourself, just change the appropriate places in `Style["MUSEUM", FontFamily -> "Arial"]`.

Comment: @J.M. I know that, but I am asking the author of the answer if he came across some examples during development and testing that are interesting enough to share with us. He must have done some experimenting.

Comment: @VividD Actually I haven't come up with anything specifically fancy myself, but `reg` can be substituted with any geometric region (although mesh region is probably required for performance). Tweaking of distribution of properties of candidate lines and adding an exponent to weight values are two additional variations which come to my mind...

Answer (score 35):

Another way that produces a more uniform distribution of lines is to take the `DistanceTransform` of the text. I start with the text itself:

```
image = Rasterize@Graphics[
   Text[
    Style["MUSEUM", 64, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"]
    ], ImageSize -> {360, 200}]
```

[image]

And the use the distance transform:

```
ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform@ColorNegate@image
```

[image]

as probability weights of points:

```
probs[res_:0.01] := Rescale[
    Flatten[
     ImageData[
      ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform@ColorNegate@image
      , DataReversed -> True]
     , 1]
    , {-res, 1}] -> Flatten[Transpose@Array[List, {360, 200}], 1];
```

Note I rescale the probabilities by `res` so that points corresponding to absolutely black regions have slightly more than zero probability of being picked.

Now I choose a lot of points at random but make sure that their x-coordinates are within a certain threshold, here `25` (if you notice, same thing happens in the image you posted):

```
{Opacity[0.05], Line@#} & /@ 
  Select[RandomChoice[probs[], {20000, 2}], 
   Norm[#[[1, 1]] - #[[2, 1]]] < 25 &] // Graphics
```

[image]

This is promising! Two parameters are key here: the amount by which you rescale the probability of black pixels and the threshold of x-coordinates you allow. Depending on how you choose these you need to use more or fewer lines and higher or lower opacity to achieve the desired result. Here's my attempt at the actual one:

```
{Opacity[0.09], Hue[RandomReal[]], Line@#} & /@ 
  Select[RandomChoice[probs[.15], {50000, 2}], 
   Norm[#[[1, 1]] - #[[2, 1]]] < 36 &] // 
 Graphics[#, Background -> Black] &
```

[image]

Finally, here's a pretty gif showing the effect of harmonically varying the threshold:

```
Table[{Opacity[0.09], Line@#} & /@ 
   Select[RandomChoice[probs[.15], {10000, 2}], 
    Norm[#[[1, 1]] - #[[2, 1]]] < Floor[36 + 15 Cos[i]] &] // 
  Graphics, {i, 0, 2 π - π/12, π/12}]//Export["pretty.gif",#]&
```

[image]

Comment: I feel better upvoting that answer than the butt's one!

Comment: I don't exactly know how to respond but thanks!

Answer (score 7):

FYI the algorithm for those letters is simply:

Say each of the six lettes is one unit width.

1. Draw a **vertical line** on the left of the screen.
2. Take a random step to the right $0.03$ to $0.1$ units (just tune these two figures to get the look of the original; it's about $3\rightarrow10$) and draw another vertical line.

   You'll end up with roughly $100$ vertical lines across the screen.

   When I say "vertical line" make them say $70\%$ (slightly randomize that, not too much) the height of the screen; and just randomize their position up down down the remaining $30\%$.

   For the other lines, it's remarkably simple,
3. Take any random point at all on the surface of the text.
4. Take any random angle.
5. Take a random length from $30\%$ to about $60\%$ the height of the screen.

Simply repeat step (3) until you get the density you want.

It's that simple, that's all there is to it.

Problems in the answers already presented above (that is to say differences from the final look of the given samples) are:

i) Y'all forgot the vertical lines.

ii) There's no need at all to go from one point in the text mesh to another point in the text mesh. Simply follow the recipe at 3-4-5 above.

Note: in (4) above it's possible they have biased the angle to something like "any angle $-70°$ to $+70°$" rather than just "any angle". Just try it.

PS Couldn't be bothered adding yet another network account for this! Cheers!